# Spring MongoDB - How to connect to replica set?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kubernetes, replicaset, spring-mongodb

I'm running locally a statefulset replica of MongoDB on Minikube and I'm trying to connect to this one using Spring Mongo DB.

In the configuration properties I have:

`spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongod-0.mongo:27017/test`

The problem is that, when I try to deploy the application locally, I receive this error:

`com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongod-0.mongo: Name or service not known`

Looks like I can't enrich the deployed replica but I don't know why.

The statefulset, the service and the pods are running correctly.

Here is the configuration of them:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongod
spec:
  serviceName: mongodb-service
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: mongo
        environment: test
        replicaset: MainRepSet
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
        - name: mongod-container
          image: mongo
          command:
            - "mongod"
            - "--bind_ip"
            - "0.0.0.0"
            - "--replSet"
            - "MainRepSet"
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 0.2
              memory: 200Mi
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mongodb-persistent-storage-claim
              mountPath: /data/db
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: mongodb-persistent-storage-claim
        annotations:
          volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: "standard"
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    role: mongo
```

Someone has any idea how I could connect my application to the replica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's due to your service name is : **mongodb-service**

You have to use always **service name** in connection strings everywhere mostly.

Traffic flow goes like :

```
Service -> deployment or statefulsets -> PODs
```

now you have exposed the service name and port(27017) and K8s will auto manage the service name into internal DNS, so you can use the name for the connection string.

Your application will be only able to connect on **service name** if running on the same K8s cluster.

**Example** :

`spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongo-service:27017/test`

You can follow this article also for refrence. : https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-deploy-spring-boot-and-mongodb-to-kubernetes-minikube-71c92c273d5e

Comment: So the properties file should be like that? `spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongod-0.mongodb-service:27017/test`

Comment: why you are adding the `mongod-0` ?

Comment: Because this is the name of the pod: pod/mongod-0                                1/1     Running   0              155m

Comment: you dont need to use pod name read the answer above how flow works.

Comment: I'm running the application locally. When I try to use the configuration suggested by you, I get this error: `com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongo-service: Name or service not known`

Comment: obviously minikube creat own virtual network so it wont be able to connect, now either you have run your application on same cluster or you have to expose the service as `Node port`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242720/discussion-between-harsh-manvar-and-liviubiur).